# Python lists don't change values correctly when assigned to to other lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I encountered an error in my Python 3 code, and after intense debugging, I found out that Python doesn't appear to assign lists correctly:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_1 = [12, 34]
>>> test_1
[12, 34]
>>> test_2 = [12, 34]
>>> test_2
[12, 34]
>>> test_2 = test_1
>>> test_2
[12, 34]
>>> test_1[0] = 'This changes in both arrays!'
>>> test_1
['This changes in both arrays!', 34]
>>> test_2
['This changes in both arrays!', 34]
>>>
```

Why is this happening? Is this intended? How do I stop it from happening???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `test_2 = test_1` you are making test_2 point to the list pointed by test_1.

You could do instead:

```
>>> test_2 = test_1.copy()
```

Comment: or `test_2 = test_1[:]`

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.  Python lists pass by reference.  This means that when you assign a list, instead of making a copy of the list and assigning this new list to the new variable, it has both variables point at the same underlying list.  This can be useful in a lot of cases.  But it seems like you want to actually copy the list.  To do so, do the following:

```
test_2 = list(test_1)
```